# 1.Error Message "Failed to Fetch Updates" 2. Negative Terminal Response to sudo apt-add-repository

Tags: release-hera, repositories

Only had E.OS 5.1 Hera a few days and have encountered 2 issues which I cannot resolve and can be best explained by the two uploaded screenshots. The 1st - this dialog appears whenever I open the app repository and only started to appear after I downloaded via terminal the repositories required for flatpak and sideloading. At the same time I installed FreeFileSync from the online flathub repository.The dialog mentions the possibility of manually downloaded repos as being a possible cause but would like to check with other users.[image] The 2nd - I am endeavouring to install the repos necessary for the installation of Timeshift and have been following a procedure shown in an online tutorial. Despite having used the precise same syntax as the tutorial shows the response is as shown. I would truly appreciate any assistance that any one can offer. Many thanks - Bob Deb

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue appears to be an issue connecting to the Ubuntu archives at `au.archive.ubuntu.com`.
If that's the issue perhaps its temporary.
I can connect to the server just fine.
In case it is related to other repositories configured, can you run the following command from a terminal and show the output.
This will show your system's configured repositories.

```
grep -r --include '*.list' '^deb ' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

For your second problem, the command `add-apt-repository` is provided by the `software-properties-common` package so you just need to install that.

```
sudo apt -y install software-properties-common
```

Comment: Looks like I am breaking protocol here by sincerely thanking you for 1. Connection to the server has been re-established without any further action by me.  2. Installing software-properties-common has enabled me to successfully install Timeshift. This has been my first post and I am totally unfamiliar with the associated protocols but I can see that there is some sort of voting procedure involved. I will be endeavouring to award your answer maximum points possible but, if through procedural ignorance on my part that doesn't materialise, you can rest assured I am extremely indebted to you.

Comment: Sorry to be a nuisance, but I am unable to find the procedure for logging off from stack exchange. I expected to click on my avatar and select "Log Out" from a drop down menu but this is not the case. I have tried every other conceivable method but without success. Could some kind person steer me in the right direction? Many thanks - Bob Deb.

Comment: You're not a nuisance and you're welcome  You should be able to mark an answer as your selected answer, but no worries about that. What's funny is I couldn't find the log out button either. I've never tried to logout before now. It's hidden under the hamburger menu in the top right corner. Just click that button and a _log out_ button should appear. Cheers!

Comment: Found him! Once again many thanks.